# React-apollo + material-ui: server side rendering not work with express

Tags: graphql, material-ui, react-apollo, server-side-rendering

I have a big problem to make a boilerplate for a complete react application using graphql (react-apollo) and material-ui.
I trying a lot of shit, but i always as the same problem:

`Warning: Prop "className" did not match. Server: "MuiSvgIcon-root-60 MuiListItemIcon-root-127" Client: "MuiSvgIcon-root-60 MuiListItemIcon-root-123"`

if i'm logged (problem is come from the Drawer component visibly), and:

`Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <h1> in <div>.`

if i'm logout (the Drawer is not showing).

You can found the complete example here: https://github.com/CocoJr/docker-sf4-elasticsearch-graphql-react-express/tree/master/volumes/node

This is my server.js file: https://github.com/CocoJr/docker-sf4-elasticsearch-graphql-react-express/blob/master/volumes/node/src/server.js

Thx a lot man.

Comment: Ok now i've a last problem with a warning about <div> in a <div>. visibly, facebook want to remove this warning. No side effect on my project so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my bug:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10649#issuecomment-408624288

Just using this in your bash works fine: `sed -i 's/material-ui\/core\/SvgIcon/material-ui\/core\/es\/SvgIcon/' 'node_modules/@material-ui/icons/es/utils/createSvgIcon.js'`

And be sure to ALWAYS use /es versions of material-ui, particulary for the SvgIcon coming with @material-ui/icons/... => @material-ui/icons/es/...